# Find a cells value (text) based on two criteria

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I've spent the majority of my afternoon looking for a way to return a text value in a cell based on two columns.  I'm looking to match a values from Sheet1, columns A & F to sheet2, returning the value in column B where these two match into sheet 1.

To visualize:

```
   Sheet 1                      Sheet 2


 A           F                A       B        F

 x           b                x       c        y
 x           g                x       k        b
```

Is there a way to use VLOOKUP to do this that I missed?  I'm pretty confident that I'm missing something simple, but it's giving me a hard time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values in Sheet 2 Column A and F going to be all unique or will they repeat?

Comment: Some will repeat, in the columns individually, but there will only be a single combination where both are present.

Comment: In that case you will need VBA for a quick and easy loop. Do you know how to code in VBA?

Comment: A little, I can usually manage to get it with guidance!

Comment: https://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/

Comment: @Tim, Well call me an idiot but I had never played with Ctrl+Shift+Enter to create an Array on a Formula and an Index+Match does the trick for this one. This formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter works =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1&F1,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!F:F,0)),"Not Found")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Subscript does exactly what you asked:

```
Sub DoThaThing()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow1 As Long
    Dim Sheet1A As Variant, Sheet1F As Variant, firstFound As String
    Dim findData As Range
    lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow1 Step 1
        Sheet1A = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
        Sheet1F = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "F").Value
        Set findData = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Sheet1A, _
                       After:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not findData Is Nothing Then
            'First instance found, loop if needed
            firstFound = findData.Address
            Do
            'Found, check Column F (5 columns over with offset)
                If findData.Offset(0, 5).Value = Sheet1F Then
                    'A and F match get data from B (1 column over with offset)
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = findData.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    'F doesnt match, search next and recheck
                    Set findData = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:A").FindNext(findData)
                End If
            Loop While Not findData Is Nothing And firstFound <> findData.Address
        Else
            'Value on Sheet 1 Column A was not found on Sheet 2 Column A
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = "NOT FOUND"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: Infinite Loop Fixed.

Comment: Thank you!  Now, if I wanted to add a third qualifier into this, would I be able to simply add the following code:                                                >''Check for Costing Method 1
                SecondFound = FindData2.Address
                Do
                    If findData.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1 Then <  Between Checking F and rechecking it if it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, before the "Exit Do" you add another If to check for the 3rd qualifier, make sure that you move the Exit Do and the FindNext inside the new Qualifier. Sounds complicated but it almost is a copy and paste of the 2nd qualifier. Since you are checking for a 3rd value, if it fails you need to add the FindNext in there and if it finds it you need to add the Exit Do to make sure it continues to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it's work for me :

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()


' Active workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'*******************************************
'Adapt this vars


'define your sheets
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet
Dim ws_2 As Worksheet
Set ws_1 = wb.Sheets("Feuil1") 'change name of the sheet to complete
Set ws_2 = wb.Sheets("Feuil2") 'change name of the sheet with all data

'definie the last Rows
Dim lastRow_ws1 As Long
Dim lastRow_ws2 As Long

lastRow_ws1 = ws_1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'if you need, adjust column to find last row
lastRow_ws2 = ws_2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'if you need, adjust column to find last row
'*******************************************

Dim keyMach1 As String
Dim keyMach2 As String

For j = 1 To lastRow_ws1

    For i = 1 To lastRow_ws2

    Dim keySearch As String
    Dim keyFind As String

    keySearch = ws_1.Cells(j, 1).Value & ws_1.Cells(j, 6).Value 'I concat both cell to create o key for the search
    keyFind = ws_2.Cells(i, 1).Value & ws_1.Cells(i, 6).Value ' idem to match

    If keySearch = keyFind Then
         ws_1.Cells(j, 2).Value = ws_2.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If


    Next i

Next j

End Sub
```